# ArcPy: Initialize zero valued grid Raster and iteratively increment

Tags: arcpy, raster

I'm jumping right into `ArcPy` to help out a friend who needs to automate some ArcGIS work. The problem at hand can be reduced to the following pseudocode:

```
accumulationRaster = SomeZeroedRaster
for each Raster pair, R, S, pertaining to rain and snow:   
   accumulationRaster += Con(S == 0, Con(R >= 1, 1, 0), 0)
```

In other words, iterate through all data of rain and snow of each day. Perform a logical operation on each cell pair, so that the corresponding cell in the `accumulationRaster` gets incremented if no snow (`S == 0`) and some rain `(R >= 1)`.

Having no luck so far with various attempts, I thought I'd ask here, as the problem should have an easy solution. Full working code with the missing gaps pointed out below. Most of it is just trivial file path set up, and the above pseudocode should suffice:

The missing pieces are numbered `1`, `2`, and `3`.

1. How to initializase a zero raster w/proper dimensions.
2. How to make a copy of this zero raster. If `1` is simple, just do this instead.
3. Increment accumulation raster.

---

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

in_workspace = "C:/Data/ProjectFolder"
os.chdir(in_workspace)
arcpy.env.workspace = in_workspace

maaneder = ["01_januar", "02_februar", "03_mars", "04_april",
            "05_mai", "06_juni", "07_juli", "08_august",
            "09_september", "10_oktober", "11_november", "12_desember"]

################ 1 ###################
baseAccum = #1: ?? (zero Raster w/correct type & dimensions)
######################################

outputPath = "rainDaysInGrowthSeason/"
for year in range(1997,2015):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        ################ 2 ###################
        monthAccum = #2: ?? (Copy of baseSum)
        ######################################

        for day in range(1,32):
            # e.g 1997/09_september/
            fpath = str(year) + "/" + maaneder[month-1] + "/"
            # e.g. 1997_09_08.asc
            filesuffix = str(year) + "_" + str(month).zfill(2) + "_" + str(day).zfill(2) + ".asc"
            # e.g. Snoedybde/1997/09_september/sd_1997_09_08.asc
            snoefile = "Snoedybde/" + fpath + "sd_" + filesuffix
            # e.g. rrl/1997/09_september/rrl_1997_09_08.asc
            rrlfile = "rrl/" + fpath + "rrl_" + filesuffix

            hasSnoe = os.path.isfile(snoefile)
            hasRrl = os.path.isfile(rrlfile)
            if (not hasSnoe or not hasRrl):
                continue

            snoeRaster = Raster(snoefile)
            rrlRaster = Raster(rrlfile)

            ############## 3 #####################
            monthAccum = #3: ??
                         # something a'la:
                         # += Con(snoeRaster == 0, Con(rrlRaster >= 1, 1, 0), 0)
            ######################################

        # e.g. rainDaysInGrowthSeason/1997
        outputDir = outputPath + str(year)
        if (not os.path.isdir(outputDir)):
            os.mkdir(outputDir)
        monthAccum.save(outputDir + "/r_" + str(year) + "_" + str(month).zfill(2))
```

Comment: I think you may want to look into raster calculator/addition 
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005m000000mv000000 
It would be helpful if you mentioned what results you got / why they aren't working, or what errors you are running into.

Comment: You identify three "missing" pieces that to me equate to three questions.  I recommend that you edit your question to focus it on whichever is the most important of these to get answered first, and to try and supply a code snippet for just that which runs up to where you are stuck (and it probably errors).  Then the others will be easier to research/ask separately.

Comment: I think that initializing an empty raster is simple enough ([see here for code snippet, example implementation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000s4000000.htm)) that the third question ("incrementing" accumulation) can stand on its own here.

Comment: Have you considered other approaches to this calculation, such as (a) computing `((S==0) AND (R >= 1))` for each date and (b) applying [local statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Cell_Statistics/009z0000007q000000/) to those results? By utilizing such built-in procedures the work might be simpler, clearer, and possibly much faster.